# Issue with regex in ASP.net for german, french & spanish languages

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to support German, French & Spanish characters on a particular field of my website. I need a regex for this. Presently I am using -

```
^[\w\s-\+\$\*\.\?\:\;\!\,&quot;'\%\&\/\(\)\@\#«»£°¿¡_ÀÂÆÇÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜàâæçèéêëîïôœùûüÄÖäößÁÍÑÓÚáíñóú\u201E\u201C\u201D\u20AC]{1,255}$
```

This regex basically uses all the char set from the 3 languages I mentioned.

Is there a neat way to avoid this lengthy regex? I tried `/p{L}/p{Z}` regex. However this didnt work.

My website is in ASP.net

Comment: `However this didnt work` - please expand on that. Why did it not work? What was happening that shouldn't have? What was not happening that should have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `/p{L}/p{Z}` is wrong, should be `\p{L}\{Z}`.
2. all the letters, like "ÀÂÆÇÈ" shouldn't be needed, they are all included in \w in .net!
3. You don't need most of the escaping in a character class
4. You can't write something like `&quot;` in a character class, only thing what happens is that every single character is added to the class.

This should be quite similar to what you used:

```
^[-\p{L}\p{N}\p{P}\p{Z}_+$*%&/@#«»£°\u201E\u201C\u201D\u20AC]{1,255}$
```

I haven't checked those Unicode codepoints at the end of the class, I don't now if they are needed or not.

For an explanation of all the `\p{...}` items see [Unicode Regular Expressions on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)